# How to create connection(s) to a Datasource in Spark Streaming for Lookups

Tags: apache-spark, redis, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I have a use case where we are streaming events and for each event I have to do some lookups. The Lookups are in Redis and I am wondering what is the best way to create the connections. The spark streaming would run 40 executors and I have 5 such Streaming jobs all connecting to same Redis Cluster. So I am confused what approach should I be taking to create the Redis connection

1. Create a connection object on the driver and broadcast it to the executors ( Not sure if it really works as I have to make this object Serializable). Can I do this with broadcast variables?
2. Create a Redis connection for each partition, however I have the code written this way

   `val update = xyz.transform(rdd => {
       // on driver
         if (xyz.isNewDay) {
          .....
         }
    rdd
   })
    update.foreachRDD(rdd => { 
         rdd.foreachPartition(partition => {
           partition.foreach(Key_trans => {
            // perform some lookups logic here
           }
         }
       })`

So now if i create a connection inside each partition it would mean that for every RDD and for each partition in that RDD I would be creating a new connection.

Is there a way i can maintain one connection for each partition and cache that object so that I would not have to create connections again and again?

I can add more context/info if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*1. Create a connection object on the driver and broadcast it to the executors ( Not sure if it really works as I have to make this object Serializable). Can I do this with broadcast variables?*

Answer - No. Most of the connection objects are not serializable due to machine dependent data associated with connection.

*2. Is there a way i can maintain one connection for each partition and cache that object so that I would not have to create connections again and again?*

Ans- Yes, create a connection pool and use it in partition. here is the style. You can create a connection pool like this https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/redislabs/provider/redis/ConnectionPool.scala

and then use it

```
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
    // ConnectionPool is a static, lazily initialized pool of connections
    val connection = ConnectionPool.getConnection()
    partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => connection.send(record))
    ConnectionPool.returnConnection(connection)  // return to the pool for future reuse
  }
}
```

Please check this:
[design pattern for using foreachRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd)